# Listen Custom Events on Main Class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

here is my little issue in actionscript. sake of simplicity I put together two tiny classes to demonstrate my problem.

so from the  RedState.as I dispatch custom event, witch passes string to listeners. I want listen to this event and grab passed string in root class.

if I listen same event in another class everything seems OK but main class have  no reaction :( :D

```
package 
{
    import assets.ButtonController;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public var nameCollection:Array
        public var sManager:SceneManager
        public var cText:TempClass
        public var bManager:ButtonController;

        public var red:RedState
        public function Main():void 
        {   
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        public function init (e:Event):void {
            red = new RedState();
            addChild(red);
            addEventListener(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT, red_sendText);

        }

        public function red_sendText(e:TextDispatcher):void 
        {   trace ("Something")
            trace (e.url)
        }





    }

}


package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class RedState extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "assets/states/red.png")]
        public var Red:Class;

        public var red:Sprite;

        public function RedState() 
        {
            red = new Sprite();
            red.addChild(new Red());
            addChild(red);
            dispatchEvent(new TextDispatcher(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT, "I wanna Sing!!"))

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to dispatch the `TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT` from the `RedState` class. Assuming everything is setup correctly there are 2 reasons as to why the event is not being dispatched. The first is you did not add the listener to the `RedState` instance. That is:

```
public function init (e:Event):void {
    red = new RedState();
    red.addEventListener(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT, red_sendText);
    addChild(red);
}
```

Adding that will allow the dispatchEvent to work from `RedState` as now the `RedState` instance will be listening for it. But there is another issue in the `RedState` constructor:

```
public function RedState() {
    red = new Sprite();
    red.addChild(new Red());
    addChild(red);
    //trying to dispatch here will not work
    dispatchEvent(new TextDispatcher(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT, "I wanna Sing!!"))
 }
```

You are trying to dispatch the event before the listener has been added. There isn't any object with a listener for this event currently so it can never run `red_sendText()`.

Therefore you should do something like this instead:

```
public function init(e:Event):void {
    red = new RedState();
    red.addEventListener(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT, red_sendText);
    red.runText();
    addChild(red);
}
```

And then in your RedState:

```
public function RedState() {
    red = new Sprite();
    red.addChild(new Red());
    addChild(red);
}

public function runText():void {
    dispatchEvent(new TextDispatcher(TextDispatcher.SEND_TEXT));
}
```

Now your `RedState` instance will be listening for the event before you call `runText()`.